# TapGesture in Xamarin From Bound property

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

OK, I have a ViewCell class that is bound to a viewModel. If I create a label I can do something like this:

```
        var taskName = new Label()
        {
            XAlign = TextAlignment.Start,
            YAlign = TextAlignment.Start,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation
        };

        taskName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "CompanyName");
```

What I want to do is bind the The value of the object to a tapGesture.

```
        var tapGesturePhone = new TapGestureRecognizer ();

        var phoneIcon = new Image {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Source = "phone.png"

        };

        phoneIcon.GestureRecognizers.Add (tapGesturePhone);

        tapGesturePhone.Tapped += (sender, e) => {
            var uri = new Uri("tel:" + );
            Device.OpenUri(uri);

        };

        //uri.setbinding("Uri.text", "PhoneNo")?
```

Any Ideas as to how I can do this? a work around would be fine too.

I have a model named `ProjectContacts` With a `ProjectContactsViewModel` set as its `BindingContext`.

My ContentView looks like this:

```
public ProjectContactsView ()
    {
        //bind the view model to the context
        this.BindingContext = _viewModel;

        _list.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ProjectContactsListCell));
        _list.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
        _list.GroupDisplayBinding = new Binding("Key");
        _list.GroupHeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ProjectContactsListHeaderCell));
        _list.HasUnevenRows = true;
    }
```

> Solution

Thanks to @Sten Petrov I managed to fix this. I ended up having to declare a new instance of my ProjectContactsViewModel inside my `ViewCell`

```
private TapGestureRecognizer tapGesturePhone = new TapGestureRecognizer ();
tapGesturePhone.BindingContext = new ProjectContactsViewModel ();
```

Then I bound my TapGestureRecognizer in the ViewCell this way:

```
tapGesturePhone.SetBinding<ProjectContactsViewModel> (TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, vm => vm.DialPhoneCommand);
tapGesturePhone.SetBinding<ProjectContactsViewModel> (TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty,vm => vm.PhoneNo);
```

From Here I just had to Create a `Setter and Getter` for the ViewModel and init the Command in the constructor:

```
 public Command DialPhoneCommand {get;set;}
 public string PhoneNo { get {return "http://google.com"; } set{ PhoneNo = value;}}
 public ProjectContactsViewModel ()
            {
                //Assign the dialcommand.
                DialPhoneCommand = new Command((phoneNo)=> 
                    Device.OpenUri(new Uri(phoneNo.ToString())));

            }
```

Comment: How are you storing the Phone Number against your phoneIcon?

Comment: @Paul Diston storing? You mean how do I get the object? I do a HttpGet to Azure for a Object that includes a lot of information such as PrimaryPhoneNo among much more.

Comment: No I mean how are you storing it, for example, once you have downloaded the data, which property stores the Phone Number?

Comment: @Paul Diston I run a InvokeApiAsync that sets the object `ProjectContacts` which is part of the ViewModel that is bound to the ViewCell.

Comment: In your Tapped event handler, you could cast the sender as an Image, check it's BindingContext, which should be an instance of the ViewModel which is bound to the ViewCell, you can then access the Phone Number from this ViewModel instance.

Comment: @Paul Diston could you show me some code? I tried the casting, but The lowest I can go is to `((Image)sender).BindingContext` and then I have not way to get an inside property of assign the context values to the URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Command` in your `ProjectContactsViewModel` and bind the tapGesture.Command to that.

The same way you bind

```
 taskName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "CompanyName");
```

you can bind the command of a tap gesture

```
    var tapGesturePhone = new TapGestureRecognizer ();
      tapGesturePhone.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty,"DialPhoneCommand");
tapGesturePhone.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty,"PhoneNo");

      var phoneIcon = new Image {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Source = "phone.png" 
      };

  phoneIcon.GestureRecognizers.Add (tapGesturePhone);
```

The command could be initialized in `ProjectContactsViewModel` (for simplicity):

```
... ProjectContactsViewModel { 
  public string PhoneNo {get;set;} 
  public Command DialPhoneCommand {get;set;}
  ...
  public ProjectContactsViewModel(){
    DialPhoneCommand = new Command((phoneNo)=> 
      Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel:" + phoneNo ));
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. you made my day. I will accept the answer as soon as I try it out. I didn't know you could create input parameters for the command.

Comment: @ Sten Petrov For some reason the command is not working. What is `PhoneNo{get;set;}` being used for? my class has not use for it.

Comment: When you say "not working" - what are the symptoms? Doesn't compile, throws exceptions, tapping the icon has no effect...? PhoneNo is just for the sake of completeness of my example - you can get your phone number from wherever it already is

Comment: Nothing happens... I am checking everything right now. tapping causes not action.

Comment: try setting the tapGesture.Command directly, without binding, same goes for the CommandParameter

Comment: I found a workaround. (Not the best solution, but it works) Thanks.